# In Ubuntu 9.10, how do I keep my name from showing in the top-right-hand corner?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, gnome

I want to keep the functionality of this applet (shutdown, restart, etc.), but only display the icon--not my name. I can't seem to find a setting for this--how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not possible to configure the applet to hide the username at this time. You can right click the applet to remove it, and access the options running commands, first hitting Alt-F2, i.e. poweroff, reboot, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the running-man icon and choose Preferences.  Under Appearance, pick something other than your name.

Comment: When I right click, there is no "Preferences" option. Only "About", "Remove from Panel", "Move" (grayed out), and "Lock To Panel" (checked).

Comment: What does the "About" box contain?  You may be using a different GNOME panel applet than I am.

Comment: "indicator-applet-session 0.1"

Comment: Aha!  I have the "Fast User Switch Applet".  You could remove the indicator-applet-session from the Panel entirely and replace it with the Fast Switcher.